# how to transpose every 3 rows

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

i have scenario where need to transpose every 3 rows to 3 columns in sequence in kettle:
input is like below for example: every 3 records belongs to one user

UserID: A1234
UserName:Abcd
Group: Group1
UserID:B234
UserName:BCDE
Group:Group2

need to transpose like below in kettle
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGasG.png)

UserID, UserName, Group
A1234,Abcd,Group1
B234,BCDE,Group2

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple to achive this using `Row Flattener` step.

The official document about this step is [here].(https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/9.0/Products/Row_Flattener)

Here is my sample
[image]